# Rails Model test with minitest and fixture

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, fixtures, minitest

I've a test in minitest:

```
class CompanyTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def setup
    @company = companies(:default)
  end

  test 'permalink should present' do
    @company.permalink = "     "
    assert_not @company.valid?
  end
end
```

Fixture for default company is:

```
default:
  name: 'default'
  website: 'www.example.com'
  permalink: 'default'
```

I have validation on company model as(company.rb):

```
validates :permalink, presence: true,  uniqueness: true
  before_validation :add_permalink

private
  def add_permalink
    self.permalink = self.name.to_s.parameterize
  end
```

Surprisingly the test is failing.

```
  test_0001_permalink should present                              FAIL (95.55s)
Minitest::Assertion:         Expected true to be nil or false
        test/models/company_test.rb:31:in `block in <class:CompanyTest>'
```

I had put a binding.pry on inside rails active-model validator: `ActiveModel::Validations::PresenceValidator`

```
class PresenceValidator < EachValidator # :nodoc:
      def validate_each(record, attr_name, value)
        binding.pry
        record.errors.add(attr_name, :blank, options) if value.blank?
      end
    end
```

Here the record still has permalink as `default`.

```
[1] pry(#<ActiveRecord::Validations::PresenceValidator>)> record
=> #<Company:0x007f9ca5375070
 id: 593363170,
 name: "default",
 created_at: Wed, 15 Apr 2015 17:59:56 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Wed, 15 Apr 2015 17:59:56 UTC +00:00,
 website: "www.example.com",
 permalink: "default"
```

Can anyone help me understand why the test is failing and why the record in `ActiveModel::Validations::PresenceValidator` still exactly matches with fixture data?

UPDATE: 
Its because of before_validate, which essentially sets the permalink according to `name`.

Comment: You are sure you want assert_not @company.valid? You are testing for an invalid company? It looks like its getting the 'default' that it needs with a blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have added a before_validation and when you are calling `valid?` method it trigger before_validation hook and as you are setting it as name of company and in this case name of comapny is `default` so that you are getting it in console as 'default'.

You are explicitly setting the permalink in before_validation hook and testing it for invalid case, which is not possible.

Comment: You are right. I had figured it out and posted few minutes back in edit section. Somehow it did not get save! Thanks.